# Raising a loaded event on jQuery Ajax .load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app that has a 1 page with a DIV that changes its content when the user clicks part of my navigation bar (which is contained within the same page).

So here is my div that I have in my one page app

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Now I populate this DIV with other html files using the jQuery `.load()` method (the HTML files that are fed into the .load method I have stripped of and  tags, etc, etc…)

Here’s my JavaScript

```
$("#content").load("views/"+ pageName + ".html", function(){
// do stuff… like load JavaScript files, etc...
}).fadeIn("fast");
```

This is working fine however the content which is brought to the page using the `.load()` I wish to attach a function to once it has loaded to the DOM.

So say I .load() the following contents from a HTML page using the JavaScript above

```
<p id="newText"> Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
```

I wish to raise an event once this is loaded, however I’m unsure what I should bind it to, like `.live()`, `.on()` or `.ready()`… I was thinking of something like this…

```
$('#newText').load(function() { 
   alert("Handler for .load() called for newText. This is in the DOM and loaded!");
});
```

Does anyone know how I should go about this?

*** UPDATE ***

Okay perhaps I need to explain... I am inherited this app from another developer and I think it was built with a bad architecture / model. Anyway, the pages or views that are loaded have a lot of hidden tabs / toggled content (hence me not liking the architecture) so despite the view / HTML being loaded some of its content may not be available in the DOM when first loaded. That is why I am wishing to detect when a something is loaded into the DOM on top of using the jQuery Ajax .load()

Comment: I might not be understanding, but why not use the callback on your first `$('#content').load(url, function() { //do stuff here })` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either the native [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) callback:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Or the [.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) which registers a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed.

```
$('#result').ajaxStop(function() {
    alert('Triggered ajaxStop handler.');
});
```

Comment: Side note: `.ajaxStop()` only recognizes jQuery AJAX calls which means that if you use a regular XMLHttpRequest object you have to delegate the request to jQuery if you want to rely on the callback from `.ajaxStop()`

Comment: I got round this by rewriting the rather strange architecture of the app so the answer doesn't solve my problem per se but it is a good answer. However RTFM wasn't appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which it will execute after the load is complete.

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```